# google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError - not a valid json file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'mt trying to use goole vision api but i can't run my python script without getting the following error:

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: ('File /root/GoogleCloudStaff/apikey.json is not a valid json file.', ValueError('Invalid control character at: line 5 column 37 (char 172)',))
```

My python script:

```
import io
from google.cloud import vision

vision_client = vision.Client()
#file_name = "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/"#'375px-Guido_van_Rossum_OSCON_2006_cropped.png'

file_name = '1200px-Guido_van_Rossum_OSCON_2006.jpg'

#file_name = "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/cyou_pic_folders/cyou_folder_2017_11_16_10_26_18/pi_pic_lc_2017_11_16_10_26_1800049.png"

with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
    image = vision_client.image(
        content=content, )

labels = image.detect_labels()
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Since this case has been open for a while, have you been able to find a solution? Did any of the answers below help you to address the root cause? Or do you find another way?

Answer (score 1):

DefaultCredentialsError indicates that you failed acquiring default credentials.Have you done initial set up in a proper manner?
Take a look at [vision](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/python/text)

Answer (score 1):

The error you are facing might be attributed to an issue with the service account key itself. `\n` is a control character present in the key which signifies a new line, which might be causing the issue. To solve the error, you can either validate the content of the `JSON` file or you can download the key from Google Cloud again. The key can be downloaded by following these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#setting_up_authentication).

After acquiring the service account key, the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` has to be set depending on the Operating System used.

As the final step, run the following Python code which performs a labeling task using the Cloud Vision API. The service account key will be automatically used to authenticate the labeling request.

```
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.abspath('path/to/file/sample.jpg')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)

# Performs label detection on the image file
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

The code prints out the labels which the API returns. The Vision API can detect and extract information about entities in an image, across a broad group of categories.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the authentication config. From [Using the client library](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library):

> Using the client library
>
> To run the client library, you must first [set up authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).